# Why do we choose random bases for the Fermat primality test?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

As in title, why do people usually choose random bases for the Fermat primality test as opposed to just using bases $2, 3, 4, ...$ in succession? Say we want to know if $N$ is prime/Carmichael or composite (with no preference for prime or Carmichael). We try a bunch of bases $a$ and calculate $a^{N - 1} \mod N$. Is there some structural thing that makes small bases not work as well?

Comment: well $a-1$ works for odds in general...

Comment: [Miller Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) has a discussion about the number and kind of $a$ to choose in those tests, assuming things like GRH. Choosing the $a$ randomly makes it easier to estimate a probability that the answer is wrong (when $N$ is chosen randomly too...)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee that always gives 1, so it doesn't seem to be that useful :D

Comment: @reuns thanks, that's helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $a$ is chosen randomly (and $N$ is odd), instead of working in  $\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z}^\times$ we can do our reasonning in the product of cyclic groups $\prod_{p^k\| N}\Bbb{Z/p^{k-1}(p-1) Z}$, choosing some $a$ randomly in this group,

whereas when $a$ is constrained to be in a small interval $[2,A]$, we have no idea of what kind of elements it gives in $\prod_{p^k\| N}\Bbb{Z/p^{k-1}(p-1) Z}$ thus we have no clue of what is the probability that it is a false Fermat witness.

Comment: So the main idea is that there might be something (we don't know about) that makes Fermat liars concentrate in the small interval $[2, A]$ for some $N$ and so we can't be sure of the actual probabilities? This does smell like GRH (or some similar result about distribution of primes) could show that using the first few $a$ is equivalent to choosing random $a$, unless I'm misunderstanding your point.